# Turn off "unknown publisher" message for older Windows application?

Tags: windows-7, security, uac

Anyone know how to turn off or suppress the "unknown publisher" message for a specific application? The application is a legacy version of Delphi that we use to update a LOB application. I thought clicking, run as administrator would fix this and I don't want to turn off UAC entirely for security safety reasons.

Anyone know how to tell Windows 7 that Borland or at least delphi.exe is a trusted application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can disable it only for one program. However you can disable the Digital Driver Signing feature.

Run the following commands from an elevated command prompt

```
bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
```

wait for confirmation message (This operation completed successfully) then type

```
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Anybody using this solution should be aware of the security implications of `bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON`.
"The operating system loader and the kernel load drivers that are signed by any certificate. The certificate validation is not required to chain up to a trusted root certification authority."
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/the-testsigning-boot-configuration-option

Answer (score 2):

The [Norton User Account Control tool](http://www.symantec.com/norton/theme.jsp?themeid=labs_uac&header=0&depthpath=0) is claimed for Vista, but may still work for Seven:

> The Norton User Account Control tool
>   will replace parts of the Windows
>   Vista UAC system. It will utilize the
>   UAC security feature from the Windows
>   Vista architecture, while
>   simultaneously improving
>   user-friendliness significantly. The
>   tool prompts recommendations based on
>   an assessment on the user-action i.e.
>   the signature information of the
>   executable. The tool also has a
>   “**remember me**” feature that allows
>   users to suppress future prompts from
>   the same action.

I would suggest using this on Seven with all due caution.
Create at least a system restore point before the installation.

Another safer possibility is described in [Bypass UAC for Standard Users](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/162976-bypass-uac.html) :

> This guide will help setup a Desktop
>   Shortcut for Bypassing UAC for
>   programs that require UAC
>   Administrative Permissions and allow
>   Standard Users to run these programs
>   without Administrative Access using a
>   known bypass trick in Task Manager and
>   a Desktop Shortcut, You can also use
>   this trick to launch the program via
>   command prompt or from scripts.